# Expectation of exponential of fermion bilinears

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, linear-algebra, second-quantization

I'm trying to better understand free fermion systems. In particular, I'm hoping to learn which quantities are straightforward to calculate, and which are more complicated.

How can I calculate $$\langle 0| e^{ \sum_{jk} A_{jk}c^\dagger_j c_k+B_{jk}c^\dagger_j c^\dagger_k + C_{jk}c_j c_k+D_{jk}c_j c^\dagger_k } |0\rangle$$ directly in terms of the matrices $A,B,C,D$?

The indices run from $1$ to $N$, the number of fermion operators. My hope is that this is well-known and that there will be some special case of Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff that will allow simplification.